# I can't start method when using DateTime

Tags: c#, function, datetime, methods, datetimepicker

I have some problem with my code...
I can't see the messagebox when the datetime is initialized.
What is wrong with the code? I can't find any errors at all.
I'm using a WPF modified application that supports DateTimePicker.
It looks like this:

```
    private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        startjob();
    }
    private void startjob()
    {
        DateTime start = (DateTime)DateTimePicker1.Value;
        DateTime end = (DateTime)DateTimePicker2.Value;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        if ((now > start) && (now < end))
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("It works");
        }

XAML:
<wpfTool:DateTimePicker x:Name="DateTimePicker1" Margin="506,189,192,1137" Width="227" TimeFormat="LongTime">
                </wpfTool:DateTimePicker>
                <wpfTool:DateTimePicker x:Name="DateTimePicker2" Margin="506,238,192,1088" Width="227" Height="25">
                    </wpfTool:DateTimePicker>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `start < now < end`?

Comment: without seeing what you set DateTimePicker1 and DateTimePicker2 values to, it's difficult to see what is wrong really...

Comment: Sidenote, why are you explicitly casting `DateTime`? `DateTimePicker1.Value` already returns a `DateTime` object.

Comment: @keyboardP
because if i don't use (DateTime) I get this error:
 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @NDJ I put DateTimePicker from 2013-04-14-02-55-00 to 2013-04-14-02-56-00

Comment: @keyboardP
This is the DateTimePicker:

<wpfTool:DateTimePicker x:Name="DateTimePicker1" Margin="506,189,192,1137" Width="227" TimeFormat="LongTime">

Comment: Ah I see, it's not the standard WinForm one, my bad. Just noticed `WPF` in your question. I assumed it was the same one from your previous question as that didn't have WPF tagged.

Comment: If it returns a `DateTime?` (a nullable `DateTime`), then you should be checking for null, or using `.HasValue`, and handling the null case.  When a value exists, get it explicitly, as in `DateTimePicker1.Value.Value`.  Then you don't need to cast.

Comment: @MattJohnson
Sorry but can you show me how?
I'm Still learning C# and I'm not very good at it yet.


All:
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @keyboardP
No Problem, stupid of me to not include that. 
Sorry!

Comment: You are checking exclusively with `<` and `>` so the values you provided are propably not in range.  You probably meant to check inclusively with `<=` and `>=`

Comment: @Sneakybastardd - No worries :) The difference between `DateTime` and `DateTime?` with a question mark is that `DateTime?` is known as a `nullable` type which means it can be `null`. [More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2cf62fcy.aspx). This is why you need to explicitly convert to `DateTime` because they're not the same type.

Comment: I posted an answer that should clarify things for you.

Comment: @keyboardP
That explains alot!
Thanks for clarifying that! :)
It's odd why no messagebox comes up. Does Start_click wait for startjob to do it's work?

Comment: @Sneakybastardd - Yes, Start_click will wait for `startjob` to finish but because you're not doing anything intensive it will be pretty much instant so you won't notice that it waited.

Comment: @keyboardP
Actually something odd happened. The messagebox didn't happen until I spampressed Startbutton till DateTimePicker1 started.
The clock was 03.23.00 when I wanted DateTimePicker1 to start.
It was after that when I pressed startbutton that DateTimePicker1 showed messagebox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime? start = DateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime? end = DateTimePicker2.Value;
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

if (start == null || end == null)
{
    // one of the pickers is empty
}
else if (now >= start.Value && now <= end.Value)
{
    // you selected values in range of "now"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great however. The messagebox doesn't show up if I don't press the start button when DateTimePicker1 has already started.

Quite odd.. Is Timer the best solution for that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you.  Of course nothing would happen if you don't press the button.  Your code is in the Click event of the Start button.

Comment: oh forgot that. When I click on start button, the Start button waits for Startjob to start and after that ends.